# How to fix org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value value by reflection setter of

Tags: java, hibernate

Well-known code works in the console application, but does not work in the boot string.

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property 
[by.smirnova.myweb.entity.ProductName.id (expected type = 
java.lang.Long)]; target = 
[by.smirnova.myweb.entity.ProductName@4942fb65], property value = [38]
```

https://github.com/Aliaksandr3by/myweb/blob/master/src/main/java/by/smirnova/myweb/entity/ProductName.java

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by "runtimeClasspath"  in "build.gradle"

```
configurations {
    developmentOnly
//  runtimeClasspath {
//        extendsFrom developmentOnly
//    }
}
```